# "make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified" When I run the"make all" command

Tags: windows, makefile

This is the error I see on my command prompt. What do I do to resolve this?

```
   C:\Users\john\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\quicksortframework>make all

   mpic++ -Wall -O3 -g -I.  -c main.cpp

   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, mpic++ -Wall -O3 -g -I. -c main.cpp, ...) failed.

   make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

   make: *** [Makefile:35: main.o] Error 2
```

Comment: Your makefile is trying to invoke a program named `mpic++`, and it can't be found on your system.  Either it's not installed, or its directory is not in your **Path**.

Comment: I have installed mpic++ how do I add its directory to the path?

Comment: I'm not a Windows person.  First, if you run the command that make prints (`mpic++ -Wall ...`) at your prompt, rather than through your makefile, does it work?  If it does then there's something else going on.  If not, you should google for "setting Path on Windows" for more help.